# Twig output in wrong position in html

Tags: php, twig, opencart

I write some costume controller for Opencart, and they output the twig template at the top of the page.

```
class ControllerCommonHome extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_meta_title'));
        $this->document->setDescription($this->config->get('config_meta_description'));
        $this->document->setKeywords($this->config->get('config_meta_keyword'));

        if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
            $this->document->addLink($this->config->get('config_url'), 'canonical');
        }

        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['carousel'] = $this->load->controller('common/carousel');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/home', $data));
    }
}
```

http://hellotree.thlab.ru/

output is HTML

Comment: I think there is a lot of information left... Try to provide more info, for example, some more code...

Comment: So question very simple, I have new controller with html name *carousel*, and past there to controller home page, but html output on the top of page, not in the place where need.

Comment: How are you call that controller? by route or loader class?